# rust - load environment variables into log4rs yml file

Tags: logging, rust, yaml

Is it possible to load environment variables into log4rs yml configurations file?

I have a simple rust application which uses log4rs for logging. I load the log configurations from a yml file which resides in the project root.

Now I have a requirement to get the file appender path from an environment variable. In spring/java we can do this with `${ABC}` notation in the yml file.

Is there a similar approach in rust/log4rs that I can use.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what @lbolla suggests, you can load the config file into a string of YAML text and then use `serde_yaml::from_str(&str)` to deserialize it. Then, you can use the function I write below to expand the environment variables in the `${}` format in the text. At last, you can write the expanded text out to a file and use that file to initialize your loggers.

```
use std::env;
use regex::Regex;
use regex::Captures;
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn expand_var(raw_config: &str) -> Cow<str> {

    let re = Regex::new(r"\$\{([a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*)\}").unwrap();
    re.replace_all(&raw_config, |caps: &Captures| {
        match env::var(&caps[1]) {
            Ok(val) => val,
            Err(_) => (&caps[0]).to_string(),
        }
    })
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e9ef571b0d2ce4242e04a2ef9329562)

Answer (score 1):

log4rs uses serde-yaml to parse YAML files: https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.12.0/src/log4rs/priv_file.rs.html#168

So it doesn't do any interpolation of environmental variables by default.

You'll either have to parse and build a log4rs `Config` object yourself or e.g. use regex to pre-parse the yaml file before loading. I wrote a similar library for Python some times ago: https://pypi.org/project/yamlenv/